# Changing the behaviour of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, tabs, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm designing an app and want to use a UITabBarController to manage my view controllers. However I have more than 5 view controllers to display but I don't like apples default "moreNavigationController" design for displaying additional viewControllers. I would prefer to have the 5th Tab act like a switch changing the other Tabs and there linked view controllers. I gather this is not apple's preferred usage of the Tab Bar Controller.

I have found a way to do this and it seems to work fine without error. But was wondering if this is a good idea. I have seen no other examples using this approach. Any thoughts would be appreciated. Thanks. Here's the stripped down/pseudo code:-

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.


    UITabBarController* mainTabController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    // Make the appDelegate the TabBarController delegate to process method below
    mainTabController.delegate = self;

    // Add my custom View Controllers as first four objects

    // Add a blank View Controller as the fifth object which will act as a switch

    self.window.rootViewController = mainTabController;
    [self.window addSubview:mainTabController.view];

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}




// TabBarController delegate method
// Called whenever a tab is selected
-(BOOL) tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    // Test for the 5th View Controller Tab selection  
    if (viewController == matches the fifth VC)
   {
        // Add a new set of VC to an array again with the fifth being a blank
        // which is never selected and acts as a switch

         [tabBarController setViewControllers:array animated:YES];

       // return No to ensure the 5th tab VC is not shown
       return NO;
   }


     // Again Test for the new 5th VC added above
    if (viewController == matches the new fifth VC)
    {

    // Same setup as above but selecting the original view controllers array
     [tabBarController setViewControllers:array animated:YES];
     return NO;
    }


return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that using Apple's API for something that was not the preferred usage is always a bad idea, and that's for multiples reason :

You'll need to check your code for every update that Apple makes to see if it does not break it.
You may find a way now, but as soon as you'll want to do more, you'll hit an issue.

My advice is, create you're own TabBarController, it is not that hard to make and you can make it fit your mind.

Comment: Yeah that thought crossed my mind. How would you go about creating a TabBarController is there any example code or guides for this?

Comment: I have used one time this project, it can be helpful for you : https://github.com/mhaddl/MHCustomTabBarController

Comment: Thanks for the help. Decided to have a go at creating a custom tab bar like controller. Had a read of the apple viewController guide. I never realised they could be setup this way. Cheers.